# Парень молодец нужно ли тире

Tags: грамотная-речь

Парень молодец! или Парень-молодец! (ударение на "е") Нужно ставить тире или нет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В большинстве случаев тире не ставится, так как ударение падает на "молодец" и пауза отсутствует: Парень молодЕц!

Примеры

О, Грушницкий молодЕц, и притом он мой истинный друг! ― сказал опять драгунский капитан.

Или: Директор молодЕц, всё делает правильно.

Но если делается пауза, то тире ставится: Вот дирЕктор - молодЕц!

Comment: Очень Вам благодарна за быстрый ответ.